# How to configure clang-format to use a specific convention for a header file?

Tags: c++, objective-c, clang-format

I have a header file `common.h` that is used in two projects. One project uses Objective-C and the other one uses C++.

When I edit `common.h` in Objective-C project, `clang-format` changes its braces to this style

```
typedef enum _eg {
One, 
Two
} eg;
```

And when I edit the same file from C++ project, the style is changed to

```
typedef enum _eg 
{
One, 
Two
} eg;
```

How do I tell `clang-format` to always use C++ convention for this particular header file?

I have tried adding

```
// clang-format Language: Cpp
```

to the top of the header but it didn't work.

Comment: Does it really matter? Why not just adopt the stance that "what the tool does is what we want"?

Comment: @JesperJuhl issue is I end up with unnecessary format related changes in the file. If I commit them then I end up with noise in my git logs and if I don't then I have to do the extra step of ignoring those changed lines.